# How can i change x in print("",end=x) at end of loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
for num in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    print(num, end=",")
x="I want this on a new line"
print(x)
```

The output is this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,I want this on new line
```

How can get x onto a new line without a comma in the most pythonic way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `print` one-by-one if you can; just [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and `print` all your values at once, which avoids the trailing comma and adds one and only one desired newline:

```
print(','.join(map(str, [1,2,3,4,5])))  # map to str needed because join requires strs
```

or similarly, unpack all the arguments as sequential arguments to a single `print` with a `sep` argument, without tweaking `end`:

```
print(*[1,2,3,4,5], sep=',')  # No conversion needed, print stringifies anything
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one alternative :

```
x = ','
for num in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if num == 5 :
        x = '\nI want this on a new line'
    print(num, end= x)
```

Comment: Rather than test every time, if you needed the individual `print`s, I'd be inclined to loop over all but the last element (e.g. `for num in allnums[:-1]: print(num, end=',')`), then print the last value outside the loop `if allnums: print(allnum[-1])`, then print the unrelated data. Avoids a test per loop where the result of the test is always known in advance.